# Coordinates in tweets have inconsistent longitude latitude

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, geojson, twitter-streaming-api

I've noticed in the live twitter stream that the longitude, latitude pairs for the object are inconsistent. Although the docs say the co-ordinates are displayed in the form [longitude, latitude] they appear in  different orders. Is this a bug? If  is "coordinates" guaranteed to be the correct representation?  (Assumed this the place attribute" co-ordinates" for the area bounding box match those )

Tweet 1:

```
"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1.38229787,103.89847755]},
"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[103.89847755,1.38229787]},
```

Tweet 2:

```
"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[53.34789491,-6.25940967]},
"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-6.25940967,53.34789491]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct attribute to look at here is `coordinates` since `geo` has been deprecated.

If you properly rely on `coordinates`, then locations will indeed be always represented as a collection of [longitude, latitude] arrays as specified by [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/).

Read more about these fields on the [Tweet Objects Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets).